# Sharepoint 2013 search result in table

Tags: search, sharepoint-2013

I tried finding information on customizing the display result view without success.

I need to display the search result in a table in place of the list.
in my column of the result, I need the library and some common information between the different library.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [this template](http://www.sharepointconfig.com/2013/05/how-to-create-a-simple-sharepoint-2013-people-directory/). Don't worry about "People Directory".

Answer (score 0):

did you try creating a display template. That should let you customize the search results into any shape or form including tabular

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/office365-sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/change-how-search-results-look-by-using-result-types-and-display-templates-HA104057444.aspx

http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2012/07/23/using-query-rules-result-types-and-display-templates-for-a-custom-search-sales-report-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx